# 500 Error trying to create teamember using sitefinity web services with ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, web-services, sitefinity

I am trying to call my web service in Sitefinity using ajax.  I have no problem fetching teammembers using this call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:60556/api/lawyerswebservice/teammembers",
    method: 'Get',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        dataObject = data;
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err.responseText);
    }
})
```

However, whenever I do the call below it returns a 500 error saying that the Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  I know the access token if perfectly fine.  For some reason, it doesn't seem to like me trying to post to this URL but it is what Sitefinity says they want me to post to.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:60556/api/lawyerswebservice/teammembers",
    method: 'POST',
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
    },
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "PublicationDate": "2019-12-11T15:24:17.9479664Z",
        "UrlName": "sample string 2",
        "Title": "sample string 3",
        "Speaking": "sample string 4",
        "MiddleName": "sample string 5",
        "Teaching": "sample string 6",
        "Gender": "sample string 7",
        "Prefix": "sample string 9",
        "FirstName": "sample string 10",
        "LastName": "sample string 11",
        "Suffix": "sample string 12",
        "Designations": "sample string 13",
        "PositionTitle": "sample string 14",
        "EmailAddress": "sample string 15",
        "PrimaryPhoneNumber": "sample string 16",
        "SecondaryPhoneNumber": "sample string 17",
        "FaxNumber": "sample string 18",
        "LinkedInProfileURL": "sample string 19",
        "TwitterProfileURL": "sample string 20",
        "OtherSocialMediaProfileURL": "sample string 21",
        "Content": "sample string 22",
        "ShortBio": "sample string 23",
        "ContentMeta": "sample string 24",
        "Memberships": "sample string 25",
        "SeoTitle": "sample string 26",
        "SeoDescription": "sample string 27",
        "SeoKeywords": "sample string 28",
        "CustomSortOrder": "29.0",
        "Media": "sample string 30",
    }),
    success: function () {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple.  It needs both:

```
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: 'json',
```

so it looks like this

```
$.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:60556/api/lawyerswebservice/teammembers",
                method: 'post',
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                },
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "Title": "sample string 3",
                    "FirstName": "sample string 10",
                    "LastName": "sample string 11",
                }),
                success: function () {
                    console.log("success");
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            })
```